# asp.net mvc javascript Hide table row by default if model bool property is false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I added a javascript to hide tablerow if the user click on a toggle radio button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#radio1').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == false) {
                $('#trMyTextBox').show();
            }  
        });
        $('#radio2').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == false) {
                $('#trMyTextBox').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<tr id="trMyTextBox">
<td style="width: 50%;">
</td>
<td>
<div class="col-xs-7">
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyTextBox, new {@id = "textEmail", @class = "form-control"})
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

I got it working when the user is clicking between the radio buttons. I need to make a change, from my controller, I am passing in model and if the properties like showtextbox is false, I need to hide the table row by default. How do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
<tr style="display: @(!Model.ShowTextbox ?Html.Raw("none;") :Html.Raw(""))"><td>A</td></tr>
```

A more clean solution is to not use the inline styles, but use a css class based on your Model property value.

```
<tr class="@(Model.ShowTextbox ? Html.Raw("show") : Html.Raw("hide"))"><td>A</td></tr>
```

And your css classes would be

```
.show 
{
     display: block;
}
.hide 
{
     display:none;
}
```

Comment: Very nice example, ternary operator in Razor and using the Html.Raw method.

Answer (score 1):

```
@code
var style = "display: none;";

if(Model.ShowTableRow)
{
    style = "";
}
end code    
<tr id="trMyTextBox" style="@style">
```

Set the style display as none will hide the row and it's contents by default unless ShowTableRow is true then no hidden display attribute will be applied.

Comment: I need to hide based on the model value like @Model.ShowTableRow